# Vuejs strange behavior when a list of checkboxes are updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox, vue-reactivity

Well, it's not easy to explain.

I have a **list of checkboxes** generated from **reactive data**. When you check one of the checkboxes, one of the entries of the reactive data is deleted.

**The list is then updated**.

The **next checkbox** is then placed under the mouse cursor and is **"activated" by releasing the mouse button**. This behavior is unwanted, can you see a way to avoid this?

Here is the code to illustrate this case:

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          v-on:change="toggle">
        {{ todo.text }}
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Script part:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript" },
      { text: "Learn Vue" },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle" },
      { text: "Build something awesome" }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(){
        this.todos.splice(1,1)
    }
  }
})
```

Also a live test: https://jsfiddle.net/m10jyLut/7/

I don't know if my design is correct. I would like to avoid a too hackneyed solution.

Thank you very much for your guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added "key" to v-for, which is always a good idea, and passing todo.id with toggle().

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          v-on:change="toggle(todo.id)">
        {{ todo.text }}
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Your script tag should be like this:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { id: Math.random() * 100000, text: "Learn JavaScript",  },
      { id: Math.random() * 100000, text: "Learn Vue", },
      { id: Math.random() * 100000, text: "Play around in JSFiddle", },
      { id: Math.random() * 100000, text: "Build something awesome", }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle(id) {
        this.todos = this.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id)
    }
  }
})
```

In Vue.js, it's always a good idea to add key to v-for, and working with ids for rendering operations.

Comment: I had some bugs and unwanted behaviors when I used index as key for the dynamic lists. Ever since I have been creating ids and use for key. As far as I understand, key must be unmutatable, but indexes are changes when I add or remove item.

Comment: Effectively, the unmutable identifier solves my problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: I've try with the "natural" index of Array, but this not solve problem : https://jsfiddle.net/m10jyLut/12/. The best solution is actually to add a unmutable index as you quote.